# Getting the value of a dynamically modified text input

Tags: jquery

I have a text input with the id `phone`. The input takes a number of a telephone. I am taking the input value and appending the country code right after I have removed the leading zero, so a number that is `0800657890` becomes `800657890`.

This is the code:

```
    var s = phone;
    s = s.replace(/^0+/, '');
    var cc = 380;
    var p = cc+s;
    var pn = p.toString();
    $('#phone').val(pn);
    var tel = $("#phone").attr('value');//undefined
    //var tel = $("#phone").attr('value');//[object object]
    alert('tel at this point is'+tel);
    window.localStorage.setItem("tel",tel);
```

I have tried getting the value in these two ways:

```
var tel = $("#phone").attr('value');//undefined
//var tel = $('#phone').val(pn);//[object object]
```

and I get the commented result in the two lines above.

How else can I get the value of id `phone`?.

Answer (score 0):

I did manage to solve it this way

```
var tel = $('#phone', this).val();
```